# django.db.utils.OperationalError [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

Tags: python, sql-server, django, heroku, pyodbc

I am using mssql server as my database in Django, hosted on Heroku. I am having trouble connecting to that database with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

```
#requirements.txt

asgiref
Django==4.0
pytz
sqlparse
djangorestframework
gunicorn
python-dotenv
django-mssql-backend
whitenoise
pyodbc
```

```
Config Vars

.
.
.
ENGINE: sql_server.pyodbc
```

MSSQL version: `Microsoft SQL Server 2014`

```
settings.py

'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        }
    },
```

Aptfile: `unixodbc unixodbc-dev`

Buildpacks: [image]

As for the compatibility check, the SQL server is in-fact compatible with Driver 17.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver16

Complete error:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 312, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(connstr,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1189, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/compiler.py", line 177, in as_sql
    supports_offset_clause = self.connection.sql_server_version >= 2012
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 400, in sql_server_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 614, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 218, in _cursor
    conn = super()._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 246, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 312, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(connstr,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Complete log of code being pushed to Heroku

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 369 bytes | 184.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Updated 85 paths from aec0419
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
remote:        2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
remote:        3. https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack.git
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Reusing cache
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
remote:        Hit:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease
remote:        Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
remote:        Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: W: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jammy-pgdg/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for unixodbc
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following additional packages will be installed:
remote:          libodbc2 libodbcinst2 unixodbc-common
remote:        Suggested packages:
remote:          odbc-postgresql tdsodbc
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          libodbc2 libodbcinst2 unixodbc unixodbc-common
remote:        0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 0 B/227 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 719 kB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for unixodbc-dev
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following additional packages will be installed:
remote:          libodbc2 libodbccr2 libodbcinst2 unixodbc-common
remote:        Suggested packages:
remote:          odbc-postgresql tdsodbc
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          libodbc2 libodbccr2 libodbcinst2 unixodbc-common unixodbc-dev
remote:        0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 0 B/465 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 2,504 kB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Installing libodbc2_2.3.9-5_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libodbccr2_2.3.9-5_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libodbcinst2_2.3.9-5_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing unixodbc_2.3.9-5_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing unixodbc-common_2.3.9-5_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing unixodbc-dev_2.3.9-5_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.11.3
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
remote: -----> Installing python-3.11.3
remote: -----> Installing pip 23.0.1, setuptools 67.6.1 and wheel 0.40.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting asgiref
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
remote:        Collecting Django==4.0
remote:          Downloading Django-4.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting pytz
remote:          Downloading pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting djangorestframework
remote:          Downloading djangorestframework-3.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dotenv
remote:          Downloading python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-mssql-backend
remote:          Downloading django_mssql_backend-2.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyodbc
remote:          Downloading pyodbc-4.0.39-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (352 kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: pytz, whitenoise, sqlparse, python-dotenv, pyodbc, gunicorn, asgiref, django-mssql-backend, Django, djangorestframework
remote:        Successfully installed Django-4.0 asgiref-3.6.0 django-mssql-backend-2.8.1 djangorestframework-3.14.0 gunicorn-20.1.0 pyodbc-4.0.39 python-dotenv-1.0.0 pytz-2023.3 sqlparse-0.4.3 whitenoise-6.4.0
remote: -----> Skipping Django collectstatic since the env var DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC is set.
remote: -----> odbc app detected
remote: -----> Starting adding ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
remote: -----> copied libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
remote: -----> copied msodbcsqlr17.rll
remote: -----> copied odbcinst.ini
remote: -----> copied profile.d
remote: -----> Finished adding ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 35.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v54
remote:        https://blood-link-heroku.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/blood-link-heroku.git
   de79a1c..838b433  main -> main
```

No clue why this error keeps popping up. Tired of it.

Comment: [django-mssql-backend](https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/) only supports ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server. If you need support for ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server have you tried using the modern fork [mssql-django](https://pypi.org/project/mssql-django/) instead?

Comment: okay, how do I install Driver 13 on my Heroku instance, I did try that earlier and this error keeps popping up

django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")